# vim shortcut to open a file under cursor in an already opened window

Tags: vim, vi, editors, key-mapping, gvim

In vim you can  [open a file under the cursor](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_file_under_cursor) by using the `gf` command.

One can also easily open that file in a new split window by hitting `<c-w> f`. This is a really nice and time saving feature.

However, I can't figure out, how  to open the file in an already opened split window (without creating a new one).

Comment: You may want to have a look at the `preview` feature (see `:h preview`).

Comment: Right, I use preview as well. However I didnt want to open the file in the preview window but explicitely in an other one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got all the pieces together to do the trick. The best way is to create a custom mapping for all the commands:

```
 map <F8> :let mycurf=expand("<cfile>")<cr><c-w> w :execute("e ".mycurf)<cr><c-w>p
```

Explanation:

- `map <F8>` maps on "F8" the commands that follow
- `let mycurf=expand("<cfile>")` gets the filename under the cursor and saves it in `mycurf`
- `<c-w>w` changes the focus to the next open split window
- `execute("e ".mycurf)` opens the file saved in `mycurf`
- finally `<c-w>p` changes the focus to the previous window (where we actually came from)

Comment: I tweaked your command a bit, so that it does not use the next split, but the previously used one. I also don't jump back but stay in that split:
`nnoremap <silent> <F8> :let mycurf=expand("<cfile>")<cr><c-w>p:execute("e ".mycurf)<cr>`

Comment: And if you use `<cWORD>` instead of `<cfile>` it opens the file on the correct linenumber (given the linnumber is specified after the filename like _/my/file:123_). Might break on other cases.

Comment: Er, the `<cWORD>` trick dosen't work, at least for me — if I run `edit %:50` for instance, it doesn't jump to line 50, it just edits a file named `thefileiwasin.js:50` instead. I'm in Neovim 0.5. Maybe it's a Vim-8-only thing? /=

Answer (score 4):

I searched for the same VIm's function and found out this solution which works like charm:

```
map <F8> :vertical wincmd f<CR>
```

[Source page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_file_under_cursor).

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
function! OpenFileInPrevWindow()
    let cfile = expand("<cfile>")
    wincmd p
    execute "edit " . cfile
endfunction

nmap ,f :call OpenFileInPrevWindow()<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

That can't be done easily. A `[count]` before `<C-w>f` specifies which file match on `'path'` is opened, it does *not* select an existing window. Only for the `<C-w>w` command, `[count]` means "go to existing window number".

To get that functionality, you need to write a custom mapping which either

- grabs the file, goes to the `[count]` window and emulates the `gf` command, or
- clones the current buffer to the `[count]` window, and executes `gf` there

Comment: Yes the only way to do it is to write a custom mapping. I was just having some trouble with grabbing the file under the cursor. But I think I have figured it out now

Answer (score 1):

I got annoyed enough about the above answers from 2013 not *quit* working reliably in the situations I cared about, and wrote slightly-more-robust functions to handle them. For `gF` specifically (i.e. including the "goto linenumber" functionality), as an example:

```
function! gfriend#goto_cWORD(winmotion)
  let cword = expand("<cWORD>")
  let st = match(cword, '\v\f+:\d+')
  let end = matchend(cword, '\v\f+:\d+')

  if end !=# -1
    let cword = cword[st:end - 1]
  endif

  let bits = split(cword, ':')

  let starting_window = nvim_win_get_number(0)

  " If there's no previous window, create a new one
  wincmd p
  if nvim_win_get_number(0) ==# starting_window
    execute(a:winmotion." ".bits[0])
  else
    execute("e ".bits[0])
  endif

  if bits[1]
    execute(bits[1])
  endif
endfunction
```

Usage is something like:

```
nmap <silent> <Leader>gF \
   :<C-u>call gfriend#goto_cWORD(winwidth(0) >=# 180 ? 'vsp' : 'sp')<CR>
```

I've posted the (tiny) thing [to GitHub](https://github.com/ELLIOTTCABLE/vim-gfriend), from whence you can install it as a plugin if you like:

```
Plug 'ELLIOTTCABLE/vim-gfriend'
```